Divergências Ortográficas em Terminologia Matemática e Científica: Português Brasileiro e Europeu em Comparação
aqui estão alguns exemplos que encontrei fazendo uma busca na Wikipédia.

estou procurando por mais exemplos. Poderiam me judar?

Correção: em pt-BR se usa preferencialmente "fatorial", como listado pelo Aulete e Michaelis, por exemplo. O Priberam é inconsistente em seu verbete do termo: "Nota: Variante no português do Brasil: factorial." "Grafia em Portugal:factorial."

@stafusam tem razão. já mudei aqui em minhas anotações. descobri mais uma Projecção(PE) vs. Projeção(PB).

@stafusa, esta pergunta não caberia mais no Meta?

@Schilive Penso que não, não é sobre o site ou a comunidade.

@Schilive, o que é o Meta?

@stafusa, estava pensando naquela decisão que as perguntas pedindo por recursos deveriam ficar no Meta, mas acho que está certo do mesmo jeito.

@HumbertoJoséBortolossi, O Meta é um site sobre o site. Lá, as pessoas discutem que perguntas devem ou não ser aceitas no site, notícias do site, etc.
